# Reading an HTML NodeList into an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, parsing

The sample code below currently gets an HTML page, and tries to read it into an array. The AJAX is working perfectly, and I can get a nodelist object successfully. Is it possible to somehow read this page into an array and not one singular object? Eventually I need to pull out every single member of this array individually as I am attempting in the for loop below:

```
$.ajax({
 url: "/thePageToScrape.html",
 dataType: 'text',
 success: function(data) {
      var elements = $("<div>").html(data)[0].getElementsByTagName("body");
      for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
           var theText = elements.firstChild.nodeValue;
           // Do something here
      }
 }
});
```

Comment: An array of what? Are you trying to get dom objects out?

Comment: `elements` is _not_ an array, but a _NodeList_ instance, there's a difference!

Comment: I am pulling data from a database with Javascript and I am document.write("Array of Numbers") to the screen. This is the only thing on the screen.

Comment: I am sorry, I know elements is not an array but I was hoping to make it one somehow

Comment: @user2577829: `Array.prototype.slice.apply(elements, [0]);` turns it into an array

Comment: I attempted to do what you said @EliasVanOotegem as shown below but the array length is coming up as 0 not 10 which it should be.

Comment: This line is not pulling my data from the other file. When i console.log(element.length); 0 is the output.                          var elements = $("<div>").html(data)[0].getElementsByTagName("body");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using JQuery, you can get a list of each node immediately below the body with

```
var elements = $(data).children("body").children();
```

or every node with

```
var elements = $(data).children("body *");
```

you can then loop over them with

```
$.each(elements, function(index, value) {
  var text = this.text()
//..do something with text
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If all you want, like you stated in your comment, is to turn the NodeList into an array:

```
elements = Array.prototype.slice.apply(elements);
```

That's all, really.

Comment: Yes, thank you. follow up question though, what does the [0] in this line mean exactly if it is not getting the array there?                                                  "var elements = $("<div>").html(data)[0].getElementsByTagName("body");"

Comment: It is referring to the first result in the JQuery object. Even results with one node are treated as a list

Comment: @user2577829: jQ references to dom elements are, in essence array-like objects, that wrap around a standard DOM element. By either applying `$().get(0)` or `$()[0]`, you get the DOM element itself. In this case, you're applying the `getElementsByTagName('body')` to that DOM reference, which will either return null, or an instance of the NodeList object, never an array

Comment: I changed this line var elements = $("<div>").html(data)[0].get("body"); to var elements = $().get(0) and when I try to console.log(elements.length); it comes up as elements in not defined

Comment: How ahout just `$("<div>").html(data)[0]`? jQuery returns the body by default. I just tried this in console `jQuery('<html><head></head><body><p>Foobar</p></body></html>')`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [$.parseHTML()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseHTML/) method do exactly what you want:

> Description: Parses a string into an array of DOM nodes.

```
var arrElements = $.parseHTML(data);
```

Comment: Do you know if there is an example similar to mine on stack overflow? I do not quite understand how to implement it for my case based on the link you posted